# How to pass on server name to install a msi

Tags: c#, windows, process

I don't know whether it is been asked before or not.
But I want to silently install a msi to a server and also pass the credentials.
I can see the process.startinfo class to pass the server credential.
But I don't see an option to pass the destination server name.

THnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSI packages are designed to be deployed FROM a server to clients not the other way around.
What server?
What are you trying right now that you don't see an option to pass the destination server name?

Comment: What if I want to copy the msi from one server to another.Is that possible?

Comment: When you say client you mean laptop,dekstop or it can be client server as well?

Comment: i see you have windows on your tags. Are you using server 2003?
In windows environments all computers without Active Directory are clients(laptops and desktops). There is a Domain controller server(master) and  then there are child domain controllers.

Also is not clear what method or program are you using for deploying 
this MSI package. You may want to try PURGOS to remotely manage servers, clients and deploy packages through the network. is open source so is free, just google PURGOS it should be the first result